# why does the which command output the same path twice?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

Why does this command have this output?

```
$which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Specifically, why is "/usr/local/bin/python" listed twice?

The "/usr/local/bin" directory only occurs once in my PATH.

I've only noticed this happening for homebrew installed software thus far.

I'm not certain exactly which version of the which command I am using.
But I think it comes from Apple.

```
$which -a which
/usr/bin/which
```

Comment: Is Python linked from somewhere else in the search path?

Answer (score 1):

`which` searches your PATH variable for instances of the program. With a `-a` option it lists all instances of the program's path. Your PATH variable has two instances of `/usr/local/bin`, that is why you see the program path listed twice.